# In 64-bit mode, does the ModRM.r/m value of 100b necessarily require a SIB byte to follow after you have preceded the instruction with a REX of 41?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, machine-code, addressing-mode

The AMD64 Architecture Manual Volume 3 talks about when the r/m field of the ModRM byte has a value of 100b, a SIB byte must follow. I understand that this is because you give up the ability to use the `SP` register (which is normally designated with 100b) for register indirect (with no offset) addressing in 32-bit and 16-bit systems that only have 8 GPRs. I also understand that using the `SP` this way would not be very useful as the `SP` is a dedicated stack pointer. However, when a REX prefix is used with REX.B set (41), the r/m field is expanded to four bits so that the expanded ModRM.r/m field has a value of 1100b which codes for `R12` and not `RSP`. But JWASM (an assembler that uses MASM syntax) still generates code that would seem to imply that both 1100b and 0100b for the r/m require a SIB byte to follow. It really doesn't make sense to require a SIB byte when the expanded field codes for `R12` and not `RSP` as `R12` is not the Stack Pointer. Does anyone have a full understanding of this issue?

Comment: My answer on [rbp not allowed as SIB base?](//stackoverflow.com/q/52522544) goes over all 3 of the special cases in x86-64 addressing-mode encoding, and even comments on why this design-decision might have been made (simplifying decoder and pre-decoder HW by not having to check REX.B when determining instruction length and SIB presence.)

Comment: So you are saying that the ModRM special cases do not use the extended 4-bit register fields (when a REX.B=1 or REX.X=1) but only the 3-bit pre-extended register fields for the determination of whether a SIB byte is called for or not. That's what I was hoping would not be the case. Oh well...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying, except for using `r12` as an index register (which you *can* do, but not RSP).  Read my linked answer for comments about why that but not the other.

Comment: I love it when someone like you knows what he is talking about! Thanks. Do you happen to be familiar with the mov AL/AX/EAX/RAX,AbsAdr opcodes A0~A3 instructions? Do 64-bit absolute immediate address values follow or is it something else? The AMD64 architecture manuals have missing information.

Comment: Intel's manuals are correct.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html.  Yes, a 64-bit absolute immediate.  Assemblers like GAS (`movabs 0x12345678abc, %al`) and NASM (`mov al, [qword 0x123456789ABCD]`) / and disassemblers like objdump and ndisasm all handle this correctly, it's easy enough to just try it.  Or with a `0x67` address-size prefix, they take a 32-bit absolute immediate.  (But that causes a LCP (length-changing prefix) decode stall on Intel CPUs, so often not worth saving a byte or 2 vs. a ModRM if an absolute address fits in a 32-bit signed disp32)